# Increase selected ListViewItem height using converter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I am trying the following to **increase the size of a selected listviewitem by 25%** in a listview:

```
<Style x:Key="ListView.AlternatingColors_HeightIncreaseIfSelected" 
    TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Height">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Binding Path="ActualHeight" 
                        ConverterParameter="@VALUE*1.25" 
                        RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}">
                        <Binding.Converter>
                            <Converters:MathConverter />
                        </Binding.Converter>
                    </Binding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        ...
```

But, I get an infinite loop, even though the trigger is `IsSelected`. I tried to use `Path="Height"`, but get NaN as the value into the converter.

The above is coming from a style being set on the ListView's `ItemContainerStyle`, in case my `RelativeSource` might be incorrect, but I did try a couple variations.

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Of course, this results in an infinite loop. If the height is updated, the objects ActualHeight changes, which results in a recalculation, which results in the Height being set again, which results in a recalculation... What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @NicoSchertler I just updated my question and bolded what I am doing. I am basically looking to increase the size of the selected listviewitem so that it stands out more.

Comment: Have you tried Mode=OneTime on the binding?

Comment: just hold the first height value you get inside the converter and in the next time it get into the converter check if you have the value and if you do, do nothing.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Success! If you make your comment the answer, then I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinite loop is created, because the binding target modifies the binding source. Therefore, the binding value will be calculated over and over.
Since you want to increase the height only once, just set

```
Mode=OneTime
```

on the binding. This will stop the binding to refresh, when the source changes.